# Script started on tty at boot does not handle backspace correctly

Tags: debian, systemd, tty, getty

I'm using Debian Jessie and have created a systemd service for launching a script on a tty like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Test Script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/tester/test.sh    
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOutput=tty
StandardError=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty2
TTYReset=no
TTYVHangup=no
TTYVTDisallocate=no
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

My script `test.sh` is just a readline:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Backspace test: "
exit 0
```

What happens? I can find the script running on tty2—just as expected; however, if I enter something and then use backspace to remove characters, it starts outputting things backward with enclosing slashes.

Example of inputting characters:

```
Backspace test: abc
```

On backspace three times, which should remove `abc`, it instead becomes:

```
Backspace test: abc\cba/
```

Additionally, `stty -a` gives `erase = ^?` and if I login on a tty and start `test.sh`, everything works as expected.

Why does this happen?

**Edit:** Solved by adjusting the terminal line settings using `stty`; more specifically, the option `echoprt` is of interest:

```
* [-]echoprt
     echo erased characters backward, between '\' and '/'
```

Comment: The terminal type is is not known so it is assumed to be "dumb".